# What is the difference between Spark DataSet and RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I'm still struggling to understand the full power of the recently introduced Spark Datasets.

Are there best practices of when to use RDDs and when to use Datasets?

In their [announcement](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-spark-datasets.html) Databricks explains that by using Datasets staggering reductions in both runtime and memory can be achieved. Still it is claimed that Datasets are designed ''to work alongside the existing RDD API''.

Is this just a reference to downward compatibility or are there scenarios where one would prefer to use RDDs over Datasets?

Comment: check this link also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45253013/1592191

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At this moment (Spark 1.6.0) `DataSet` API is just a preview and only a small subset of features is implemented so it is not possible to tell anything about best practices.

Conceptually Spark `DataSet` is just a `DataFrame` with additional type safety (or if you prefer [a glance at the future](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1ed354a5362967d904e9513e5a1618676c9c67a6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L58) `DataFrame` is a `DataSet[Row]`). It means you get all the [benefits of Catalyst](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) and [Tungsten](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html). It includes logical and physical plan optimization, vectorized operations and low level memory management.

What you loose is flexibility and transparency.

First of all your data has to be encoded before it can be used with `DataSet`. Spark provides encoders for primitive types and Products / case classes and as for now API required to define custom serialization is not available. Most likely it will be relatively similar to UDT API (see for example [How to define schema for custom type in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440461/1560062), [Serialize/Deserialize existing class for spark sql dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35215458/1560062)) with all its issues. It is relatively verbose, requires additional effort and can become far from obvious with complex objects. Moreover it touches some lower level aspects of the API which are not very well documented.

Regarding transparency it is pretty much the same problem as with a planner in a typical RDBMS. It is great until it isn't. It is amazing tool, it can analyze your data, make smart transformations but as any tool it can take a wrong path and leaves staring into execution plan and trying to figure out how to make things work.

Based on a preview I would say it can be placed somewhere between `DataFrame` API and RDD API. It is more flexible than `DataFrames` but still provides similar optimizations and is well suited for general data processing tasks. It doesn't provide the same flexibility (at least without a deeper dive into Catalyst internals) as a RDD API.

Another difference, which is at this moment just hypothetical, is a way how it interacts with guest languages (R, Python). Similar to `DataFrame`, `DataSet` belongs to JVM. It means that any possible interaction can belong to the one of two categories: native JVM operation (like `DataFrame` expressions) and guest side code (like Python UDF). Unfortunately the second part requires expensive round-trip between JVM and a guest environment.

See also:

- [Difference between DataSet API and DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37301226/1560062)

Answer (score 0):

DataSet
1) It is an structured API Provided by Spark to work on Table like structure. 
Where you can do your analysis or data manipulation just like the Tables on any DataBase.
2) It is a subset of DataFrame . If you chek the link you will come to lots of functions or methods supported for the DataSet
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
3) It is an High Level API

RDD
1)Are know as Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDD)
2) It is an core level API of Spark.
3) When ever you work on any DataFrame or Data sets those are converted to low level API i.e. RDD
4) These are use full whenever the business needs are exceptional and you cannot perform manipulations on DataFrame or DataSets at that time RDD can be used.
5) you need to do some custom shared  variable manipulation