# Difference between DataSet API and DataFrame API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

Does anyone can help me to understand difference between DataSet API and DataFrame API with an example? Why there was there a need to introduce the DataSet API in Spark?

Comment: It's not duplicated question, this question is about Dataset vs DataFrame, another one is about DataFrame vs RDD.