# Difference between GroupByKey($"col") and GroupBy($"col") in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What would be the fundamental difference with using `.GroupByKey` and `.GroupBy` when I am using a column name of a DF as a parameter?

Which one is time efficient and how exactly does each mean can someone please explain in detail as I went through some examples but it was confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `groupByKey` method that takes `Column` as an argument. There are methods which take functions, either:

```
def groupByKey[K](func: MapFunction[T, K], encoder: Encoder[K]): KeyValueGroupedDataset[K, T]
```

or

```
def groupByKey[K](func: (T) ⇒ K)(implicit arg0: Encoder[K]): KeyValueGroupedDataset[K, T]
```

Compared to `groupBy` that takes `Columns`:

```
def groupBy(cols: Column*): RelationalGroupedDataset
```

or `String`

```
def groupBy(col1: String, cols: String*): RelationalGroupedDataset
```

the difference should be obvious - the first two return `KeyValueGroupedDataset` (intended for processing with "functional", "strongly typed API, like `mapGroups` or `reduceGroups), while the later methods return`RelationalGroupedDataset` (intended for processing with SQL-like API).

In general see:

- [Difference between DataSet API and DataFrame API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37301226)
- [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638)
- [Difference between DataFrame (in Spark 2.0 i.e DataSet[Row] ) and RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31508083/10546212)