# Conceptual difference RDD to Dataset in Spark 2.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-2.0

I read

- [What is the difference between Spark DataSet and RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424854/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-dataset-and-rdd)
- [Difference between DataSet API and DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301226/difference-between-dataset-api-and-dataframe)
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes
- https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

In Spark 1.6 a Dataset seems to be more like an improved DataFrame (["Conceptually Spark DataSet is just a DataFrame with additional type safety"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424854/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-dataset-and-rdd)). In Spark 2.0 it seems a lot more like an [improved RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets). The former has a relational model, the later is more like a list. For Spark 1.6 it was said that Datasets are an extension of DataFrames, while in Spark 2.0 DataFrames are just Datasets containing a Type `[Row]`, making DataFrames a special case of Datasets, making DataFrames a special case of Datasets. Now I am a little confused. Are Datasets in Spark 2.0 conceptually more like RDDs or like DataFrames? **What is the *conceptual* difference between an RDD to a Dataset in Spark 2.0?**

Answer (score 0):

I thin they are very similar from an user-perspective, but are quite differently implemented under the hood. Dataset API now seems almost as flexible as RDD API, but adds the entire story of optimization (Catalyst & Tungsten)

Citing from http://www.agildata.com/apache-spark-2-0-api-improvements-rdd-dataframe-dataset-sql/

> RDDs can be used with any Java or Scala class and operate by
>   manipulating those objects directly with all of the associated costs
>   of object creation, serialization and garbage collection.
>
> Datasets are limited to classes that implement the Scala Product
>   trait, such as case classes. There is a very good reason for this
>   limitation. Datasets store data in an optimized binary format, often
>   in off-heap memory, to avoid the costs of deserialization and garbage
>   collection. Even though it feels like you are coding against regular
>   objects, Spark is really generating its own optimized byte-code for
>   accessing the data directly.